# Find related text from different file and update using sed or awk or grep

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, aix

I have two text files.
1. user.txt contains following text

```
ServerName:xyz  
Username:foo  
UserID:
```

Need to get the UserID from a different file say properties.txt and update it in user.txt.

properties.txt:

```
ServerName,Username,UserID,  
abc,joe,123,  
jkl,brad,5678,  
xyz,foo,456,
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I need a solution that should work both on AIX, Linux

thanks,

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Convoluted sed solution:

`sed -e '/Username/h;/UserID/{x;s/.*:/printf "UserID:%d" $(grep /;s/$/ properties.txt | grep -oE [0-9]+)/e}' user.txt`

This uses `h` to stick the Username in the hold space, then `x` to get that line back when the subsequent UserID line is processed.  The Username line is then turned into `printf "UserID: %d" $(grep [Username] properties.txt | grep -oE [0-9]+)` which is executed in the shell with `s///e`

If the shell doesn't support `$( ... )` syntax, then backticks might work.